# How to connect polygons to make a circle?

Tags: polygon, vector, geoprocessing, saga

I created polygons from a raster on which I ran an edge detection filter. I turned the edges into a polygon layer (multipart splitted into single parts). The intention was to have circular polygons at the end, but now there many single polygons forming one circle but are not touching each other, so I cannot connect these. The single yellow polygon in the figure below is an example.

Can anybody tell me how to connect all polygons in order to form a circle?
The polygon is available as a download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnatq08xtercn16/Public.zip?dl=0). I work in SAGA, GRASS, or QGIS, or in R.

[image]

Comment: Dear Cyril - no worries. Problem solved.

Comment: Good, I'm happy for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polygons are touching at a point.

Do a little *Buffer*, *Dissolve*, and *Multipart to singleparts* again.

There is no way to preserve exactly those geometries and to be merged.

If you wanted, you can then make a negative *Buffer* to return them to their original size, with *Round* type of *End Cap Style*, so they do not touch each other again.

Comment: Perfect! Worked very well. I simply added a small buffer (distance = 0.01). Dissolve was then done while performing the buffering. Many thanks!

Comment: @Jens, most welcome!